# Table Background color with toprule

Tags: tables, color, booktabs, colortbl, rowcolor

I want make a table with background color, when I am using \toprule,\midrule and \bottomrule  I have a white space after the rule. I want to fill the color of rule below space. MWE is below

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{colortbl}
\usepackage{array}



\abovetopsep=2pt

\makeatletter

\def\toprule{\noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi
\@aboverulesep=\abovetopsep
\global\@belowrulesep=4pt%%%I should need 4pt in below of midrule
\global\@thisruleclass=\@ne
\@ifnextchar[{\@BTrule}{\@BTrule[\heavyrulewidth]}%
}

\def\midrule{\noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi
\@aboverulesep=\abovetopsep
\global\@belowrulesep=4pt%%%I should need 4pt in below of midrule
\global\@thisruleclass=\@ne
\@ifnextchar[{\@BTrule}{\@BTrule[\lightrulewidth]}}

\makeatother

\newcommand{\mc}[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.85}
\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}

\newcolumntype{b}{>{\columncolor{Gray}}c}


\begin{document} 


\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{b | b | b | b | b}
\toprule
\rowcolor{LightCyan}
\mc{1}{}  & \mc{1}{x} & \mc{1}{y} & \mc{1}{w} & \mc{1}{z} \\
\rowcolor{LightCyan}
\mc{1}{e}  & \mc{1}{d} & \mc{1}{c} & \mc{1}{b} & \mc{1}{a} \\
\cmidrule{1-2}
variable 1 & a & b & c & d \\
variable 1 & a & b & c & d \\
\midrule
variable 1 & a & b & c & d \\
variable 1 & a & b & c & d \\
\hline
variable 2 & a & b & c & d \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to achieve the effect, you have to do the following

- reset length names that control space above and below rules in `booktabs`

```
\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
```

- manually add missing spacing using `\rule[]{}{}`.

[image]

---

EDIT. With [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray), the code can be much simplified (see the second code)

Note, in this example, I applied `booktabs` environment instead of regular `tblr` (both from `tabularray`). The former keep standard spacing around rows and maintains additional spacing around rules (similarly to `booktabs` in regular `tabular`). On the other hand, `tblr` applies its own layout: rows have slightly larger height as well as rules defined in `booktabs` do not apply extra spacing.

[image]

The MWE without `tabularray`

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{colortbl}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\mc}[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.85}
\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}

\newcolumntype{B}{>{\columncolor{Gray}}c}   % don't use existing names


\begin{document} 


\begin{table}[tbh]
    \begin{tabular}{B | B | B | B | B}
        \specialrule{\heavyrulewidth}{0pt}{0pt}
        \rowcolor{LightCyan}
        \mc{1}{}  & \mc{1}{x} & \mc{1}{y} & \mc{1}{w} & \mc{1}{z} \\
        \rowcolor{LightCyan}
        \mc{1}{e}  & \mc{1}{d} & \mc{1}{c} & \mc{1}{b} & \mc{1}{a} \\
        \cmidrule{1-2}
        variable 1 & a & b & c & d \\
        variable 1 & a & b & c & d \\
        \midrule
        variable 1 & a & b & c & d \\
        variable 1 & a & b & c & d \\
        \hline
        variable 2 & a & b & c & d \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[tbh]
    \setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
    \setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
    \newcommand\astrut{\rule[8pt]{0pt}{2pt}}
    \newcommand\bstrut{\rule[-5pt]{0pt}{5pt}}
    \begin{tabular}{B *4{|B}}
        \specialrule{\heavyrulewidth}{0pt}{0pt}
        \rowcolor{LightCyan}
        \mc{1}{}   & \mc{1}{x} & \mc{1}{y} & \mc{1}{w} & \mc{1}{z} \\
        \rowcolor{LightCyan}
        \mc{1}{e}  & \mc{1}{d} & \mc{1}{c} & \mc{1}{b} & \mc{1}{a\bstrut} \\
        \cmidrule{1-2}\astrut
        variable 1 & a & b & c & d \\
        variable 1 & a & b & c & d \bstrut \\
        \midrule\astrut
        variable 1 & a & b & c & d \\
        variable 1 & a & b & c & d \bstrut \\
        \hline \astrut
        variable 2 & a & b & c & d \bstrut\\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

The MWE with `tabularray`

```latex
\documentclass{book}
% \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
    \definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.85}
    \definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}
\usepackage{tabularray}
    \UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}


\begin{document} 
\begin{table}[tbh]
    \begin{booktabs}{
            colspec = {*5{Q[c]}},
            row{1-2} = {bg=LightCyan},
            row{3-Z} = {bg=Gray},
            hline{3} = {3-5}{Gray},
            rows = {abovesep+=-0pt, belowsep+=-0pt},
        }
        \toprule
           & x & y & w & z \\
        e  & d & c & b & a \\
        \cmidrule{1-2}
        variable 1 & a & b & c & d \\
        variable 1 & a & b & c & d \\
        \midrule
        variable 1 & a & b & c & d \\
        variable 1 & a & b & c & d \\
        \midrule
        variable 2 & a & b & c & d \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{booktabs}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Good show... `+1`

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document} 

\begin{table}
\begin{NiceTabular}{c|c|c|c|c}
\toprule
\Block[fill=[rgb]{0.88,1,1}]{2-*}{} % the \Block avoids the vertical rules
& x & y & w & z \\
e & d & c & b & a \\
\cline{1-2}
\RowStyle[nb-rows=*,rowcolor=[gray]{0.85}]{}
variable 1 & a & b & c & d \\
variable 1 & a & b & c & d \\
\midrule
variable 1 & a & b & c & d \\
variable 1 & a & b & c & d \\
\hline
variable 2 & a & b & c & d \\ \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

You won't see thin white lines in the colored panels, whatever PDF viewer you use.