# How can I create adjacency matrix of this format?

Tags: tables, booktabs

How can I create a table with empty corner and continous vertical lines like this?

[image]

Here is what I have so far:

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[!t]
  \centering
  \caption{Adjacency Matrix}
  \label{tab:Adjacency Matrix}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \toprule
$V_1$ & $V_2$ & $V_3$ & $V_4$ & $V_5$ \\
\midrule
$V_1$ \\
\midrule
$V_2$ \\
\midrule
$V_3$ \\
\midrule
$V_4$ \\
\midrule
$V_5$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Also please suggest if you have a nice idea to do it.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/640176/197451

Comment: Regarding the gaps between horizontal rules when using `booktabs`, have a look at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/652366/31283)

Comment: @jsbibra that is nice. Can I use booktab style for the nicetablular? I tried but  couldn't make it work with `\toprule`.

Comment: @Celdor I see, l'll check `\cmidrule`.

Comment: @emnha Well, I thought you would like to know what happens with the gaps. I just post a solution with [tabularray](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabulary), which also accepts `booktabs`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest to use [tabularray](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabulary) for this kind of tables or NiceMatrix but I am not familiar with the latter, so I give a solution based on `tabularray`

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tabularray}
    \UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}


\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[!t]
    \centering
    \caption{Adjacency Matrix}
    \label{tab:Adjacency Matrix}
    \begin{tblr}{
            colspec={*6{c}},
            vline{1} = {2-Z}{0.8pt},
            vline{2,Z} = {0.8pt},
            vline{3-Y} = {0.3pt},
            hline{1} = {2-Z}{0.8pt},
            hline{2,Z} = {0.8pt},
            hline{3-Y} = {0.3pt},
            row{1} = {mode=math},
            column{1} = {mode=math},
        }
        & V_1 & V_2 & V_3 & V_4 & V_5 \\
        V_1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        V_2 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
        V_3 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        V_4 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
        V_5 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    \end{tblr}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It looks very nice but somehow I got a lot of errors in Overleaf. Also how would you fix the width size for every columns and rows? 
https://ibb.co/g7kTy0T

Comment: I am afraid Overleaf is still not up-to-date and [tabularray](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabulary) is still not available. However, you can download the [zip-file](https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tabularray.zip), extracts the `tabularray.sty` and upload it in your project on Overleaf. Then it will work.

Comment: You're right. It works now. How would you fix the width size of columns and rows?

Comment: It's a typo in my code. Change `5` to `6` in `colspec={*5{c}}, ...` and it will work

Comment: It still works but for now the width of columns and rows fits the content. I want to make them fixed instead.

Comment: This is done in `colspec`, e.g. `colspec={Q[4em,c] *5{Q[2.5em,c]}}`. Expand `*5` to individual column spec. if you need every one of them to have an individual width. Besides `c` is equivalent to `Q[c]`, which is used by `tabularray` in case you want even more tunings.

Comment: If I add two more columns like the first row `& V_1 & V_2 & V_3 & V_4 & V_5  & V_6 & V_7\\`  then I get a warning like this from Overleaf: `"Package tabularray Warning: Table width is too small, need 12.20003pt more!"`. Do you have any idea to remove this warning?

Comment: It's because the document class `IEEEtran` sets two column layout and if your table doesn't fit a column width you get a warning. You have to reduce the table width somehow or enclose it within `table*` (starred) instead of regular `table` environment.

Comment: The table will no longer flow with text and will be placed at the top of the next page but will span two columns and fit the whole page width.

Comment: Thanks, I solved it by reducing the column's width.

Answer (score 3):

It's easy with the environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{NiceTabular}{>{\bfseries}cccccc}[hvlines,corners=NW] % NW = north west 
\RowStyle{\bfseries}
  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
1 &   &   & 1 & 1 &   \\
2 &   &   &   & 1 & 1 \\
3 & 1 &   &   &   & 1 \\
4 & 1 & 1 &   &   &   \\
5 &   & 1 & 1 &   &   \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

---

Answer to the comment. Usually, one uses the rules of `\booktabs` (`\toprule`, `midrule`, `\bottomrule`, etc.) only with a design without any vertical rule...

However, if you want to add rules with the thickness of a `\toprule` of `booktabs` (equal to `\heavyrulewidth`), it's possible with `nicematrix` by defining a custom style of line with the key `custom-line`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,booktabs,tikz}

\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions
  {
    custom-line = 
     {
       command = boldhline ,
       ccommand = cboldhline ,
       tikz = { line width = \heavyrulewidth } , 
       total-width = \heavyrulewidth 
     }
  }

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{NiceTabular}{>{\bfseries}cccccc}[hvlines,corners=NW] % NW = north west 
\cboldhline{2-last}
\RowStyle{\bfseries}
  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
1 &   &   & 1 & 1 &   \\
2 &   &   &   & 1 & 1 \\
3 & 1 &   &   &   & 1 \\
4 & 1 & 1 &   &   &   \\
5 &   & 1 & 1 &   &   \\
\boldhline
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Yeah, I tried this but then I wanted to apply the booktabs style like toprule, midrule and bottom rule but I couldn't add toprule as it extends all over 6 columns.

Comment: I have modified my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this may helps you:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[!t]
  \centering
  \caption{Adjacency Matrix}
  \label{tab:Adjacency Matrix}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\cline{2-5}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{$V_1$} & $V_2$ & $V_3$ & $V_4$ & $V_5$ \\
\hline
$V_1$ & & & & \\
\hline
$V_2$ & & & &\\
\hline
$V_3$ & & & &\\
\hline
$V_4$ & & & &\\
\hline
$V_5$ & & & &\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but the node V1 is not correct in the first row. Also can I use the booktab style here as well?

Comment: @emnha If you want to use the `booktabs` then try with the tag `\specialrule`