# Why does cellcolor not work here?

Tags: tables, booktabs, cellcolor

Why does cellcolor not work here?

The code is from answer of my previous question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/654457/how-can-i-create-adjacency-matrix-of-this-format/654469?noredirect=1#comment1631071_654469). I'm trying to color a cell of a table as the code [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121476/table-cell-color-overlaps-cell-border).

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}


\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[!t]
    \centering
    \caption{Adjacency Matrix}
    \label{tab:Adjacency Matrix}
    \begin{tblr}{
            colspec={*6{c}},
            vline{1} = {2-Z}{0.8pt},
            vline{2,Z} = {0.8pt},
            vline{3-Y} = {0.3pt},
            hline{1} = {2-Z}{0.8pt},
            hline{2,Z} = {0.8pt},
            hline{3-Y} = {0.3pt},
            row{1} = {mode=math},
            column{1} = {mode=math},
        }
        & V_1 &  V_2 & V_3 & V_4 & V_5 \\
        V_1 & \cellcolor{gray!25}1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        V_2 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
        V_3 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        V_4 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
        V_5 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    \end{tblr}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `tabularay` provides two ways to colourise cells: either in a table definition via `cell{rowA-rowB}{colX-colY}` or directly in the "data" via `\SetCell{...}` as @Zarko answered. If it's just one cell, it doesn't matter. But if you have a range of cells to colourise, I'd use the former way. You can change both foreground and background of cells. Try to add the following to the table definition: `cell{1}{2-Z} = {bg=blue,fg=white}, cell{2-Z}{1} = {bg=black!50!green,fg=white},`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package `tabularray` has own mechanism for coloring cells. Try the following:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\NewTableCommand\SCC[1]{\SetCell{bg=#1}}  % <--- shortcut 

\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[!t]
    \centering
    \caption{Adjacency Matrix}
    \label{tab:Adjacency Matrix}
    \begin{tblr}{
            colspec={*6{c}},
            vline{1} = {2-Z}{0.8pt},
            vline{2,Z} = {0.8pt},
            vline{3-Y} = {0.3pt},
            hline{1} = {2-Z}{0.8pt},
            hline{2,Z} = {0.8pt},
            hline{3-Y} = {0.3pt},
            row{1} = {mode=math},
            column{1} = {mode=math},
        }
        & V_1 &  V_2 & V_3 & V_4 & V_5 \\
        V_1 & \SCC{gray!25}1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        V_2 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
        V_3 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        V_4 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
        V_5 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    \end{tblr}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
you also an color cel(s) in table preamble:

```
\`[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\NewTableCommand\SCC[1]{\SetCell{bg=#1}}


\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[!t]
    \centering
    \caption{Adjacency Matrix}
    \label{tab:Adjacency Matrix}
    \begin{tblr}{
            colspec={*6{c}},
            vline{1} = {2-Z}{0.8pt},
            vline{2,Z} = {0.8pt},
            vline{3-Y} = {0.3pt},
            hline{1} = {2-Z}{0.8pt},
            hline{2,Z} = {0.8pt},
            hline{3-Y} = {0.3pt},
            row{1} = {mode=math},
            column{1} = {mode=math},
            cell{2}{2}={bg=gray!9}  % <---
        }
        & V_1 &  V_2 & V_3 & V_4 & V_5 \\
        V_1 &   & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        V_2 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
        V_3 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        V_4 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
        V_5 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    \end{tblr}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

result is the same as before.